# Unable to Make sortColumn() Work in Button with MUI DataGrid in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Using the MUI package with React, I want to use a Button to initiate a sort of a column of a DataGrid component.  The documentation describes the DataGrid apiRef as including a sortColumn() function, and it provides a signature for that function, and I think I'm invoking it correctly, but I have not been able to make it work.

Here's is a little code that should be enough to get an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```jsx
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef()
  ...some code that defines "Rows" and "Columns"...
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained"
        onClick={() => apiRef.current.sortColumn(Columns[0], 'asc', false)}>
          Sort
      </Button>
      <DataGrid apiRef={apiRef}
                rows={Rows}
                columns={Columns}/>
    </>
  )
```

Nothing happens when I click the Sort button.  Changing 'asc' to 'desc', in case I've got the directions backwards, doesn't work either.  There are no reports of problems in the console log.

Clicking on the sort arrow of the column's header works fine.

Added by Edit:

Even just letting me know that you've used the sortColumn() function successfully would be helpful information.  Possibly I'm not yet employing it correctly, but I have not yet found any reports on the web of someone successfully using it.  I'm not sure whether I should give up or should continue investing time trying to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be related to the timing of when the `sortColumn` function is called. Since the `DataGrid` component is rendered after the `Button` component, it's possible that the `sortColumn` function is called before the `DataGrid` component is mounted and the `apiRef` is ready.

To ensure that the `sortColumn` function is called after the `DataGrid` component is mounted and the `apiRef` is available, you can use the `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `apiRef`:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, DataGrid, useGridApiRef } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

function YourComponent() {
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
  const sortColumn = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sortColumn.current) {
      apiRef.current.sortColumn(sortColumn.current.field, sortColumn.current.sort, sortColumn.current.isMultiple);
      sortColumn.current = null; // Reset the sortColumn ref
    }
  }, [apiRef]);

  // ...some code that defines "Rows" and "Columns"...

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        onClick={() => {
          sortColumn.current = {
            field: Columns[0],
            sort: 'asc',
            isMultiple: false,
          };
        }}
      >
        Sort
      </Button>
      <DataGrid apiRef={apiRef} rows={Rows} columns={Columns} />
    </>
  );
}
```

In this updated code, we use the `useEffect` hook to listen for changes in the `apiRef`. When the `sortColumn` ref is set (i.e., when the Sort button is clicked), the `sortColumn` function is called within the `useEffect` hook. This ensures that the `DataGrid` component is mounted and the `apiRef` is available.

By using the `sortColumn` ref, we can store the sorting parameters (`field`, `sort`, `isMultiple`) and invoke the `sortColumn` function once the `apiRef` is ready.

Make sure to import the necessary components and hooks from the `@mui/x-data-grid` package.

By implementing this pattern, you should be able to initiate the sorting of a column in the `DataGrid` component when clicking the Sort button.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't cause any change in behavior.  The Sort button still didn't work while the sort arrow for the column header continued to work.  Also, I didn't understand why apiRef might not be ready after the page has completely rendered and only then hitting the Sort button.

Comment: At least three of your answers appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: the above answer is AI generated.  Giving it a demerit point